# Why is cuda shared memory dynamic allocation not valid here?

Tags: cuda

This works fine:

```
a_size=FindSizeAtrunTime();

Kernel<<< gridDim, blockDim, a_size >>>(count)
```

But this shows error

```
__global__ void Kernel(int count_a, int count_b)
{

a_size=FindSizeAtrunTime();
    __shared__ int a[a_size];

}
```

error: expression must have a constant value

In both cases size is being determined at runtime. So why the first case is ok, and not the second case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is illegal on two levels.

1. Firstly, C++98 (which is what CUDA mostly derived from), doesn't allow statically declared, dynamically sized arrays. The language doesn't permit it, and so neither does CUDA.
2. Secondly, and more importantly, the size of dynamic shared memory allocations must be known *before* a kernel can be launched. The GPU must know how much shared memory to reserve before a block can be scheduled. That isn't possible in your second example, whereas it is in your first example.

Comment: Thanks. your second point is now very much clear to me. But could you please elaborate further your first point?

Comment: In your second example, you are missing the `extern` keyword in front of the `__shared__` allocation which is required for a dynamic allocation.  Therefore it looks syntactically like a static allocation, and a static allocation must have a size that is discoverable by the compiler (i.e. a constant).  Even if you convert it to a proper dynamic allocation with `extern`, it would still fail for the second reason given by @talonmies.  You may also wish to review the relevant [doc section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared)